# RFID - Detecting items in box regardless of tag orientation

Tags: rfid

I'm thinking about something, and am wondering if RFID can accomplish this. Is it possible to place an RFID antenna on the bottom of a box, put an arbitrary amount of items with different shapes with RFID stickers on top, and have the antenna detect their IDs?

I saw some omni-directional antennas however they seem quite linear too. Would this work if the bottom space of the containing box is 50 cm² (20 inches²), and some of the items are placed in the same horizontal space as the reader?

Comment: There's very different kinds of RFID tags. Are you restricting yourself to a specific standard?

Comment: also, aside from the reach problem, you'd be getting in collision problems that only a few of the systems can solve. A bit of research on your side can narrow down the feasible systems pretty quickly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Honestly, my experience with the technology is a couple of hours. Basically I was looking for a solution which can reliably detect the items, and submit the data to a Raspberry Pi. I did read that collision avoidance algorithms are built into the readers. Would you suggest a couple so I can take a look? Thanks :P

Comment: Also, I believe that only the UHF ones would work for this purpose, and I've been looking at the following antenna since it already has Raspberry Pi integration. I'll post the link in the next comment for readability.

Comment: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Embedded-antenna-865-928mhz-UHF-RFID_60381922585.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.5.7d0ff787gSsZvY&s=p

Comment: Neekoy I assume you've at least read the Wikipedia RFID article. It has a specific section "Bulk Reading". Can you please specify your question based on that reasonable amount of research?